Inbox notification count does not update for chat
The inbox notification count does not update when I get a new unread chat ping.
For example, before:



After:



However, if I get a new notification on StackExchange sites (for example, via a comment), it does update correctly:



The issue seems to be only with chat, main site notifications are fine.

maybe https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/404400/997587

For a brief moment I had 38 notifications, then it became 875 after refreshing.

@starball it is indeed: "After some experimentation: chat notifications do not add to the counter. Marking them as read still subtracts from the counter."
